# Question on expect perl

Tags: perl, expect

I am new in expect perl programming and have to write some scripts to automate some tasks. Basically I need to telnet to a unix machine, issue some unix commands and check some outputs. 
I have written a small script to telnet but I have a doubt on how to check the status of the unix commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;
$timeout=10;
my $exp = Expect->spawn("telnet test-b -l regress")
    or die "Cannot spawn telnet: $!\n";;
my $spawn_ok;

$foo1=$exp->expect($timeout, 'Password:');
print "######Received Password prompt\n";

$exp->send("MaRtInI\n");
print "######Sent password\n";

$foo1=$exp->expect($timeout, '%');
print "######Received root prompt\n";
$exp->send("cd /var/tmp");
```

I have doubt here on how to check whether the cd command is actually successful, because instead of `cd /var/tmp` if I give `cd /var/temp12` (which does-not exist), I am seeing the same result. How can I check whether to unix command which I have sent through cd is actually successful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `echo $?` to find out last command exit status *on the server-side*, and then process it via `qr/^\d+/m` (m means "afrer beginning of string or newline").

I've written a sample script that does spawns an expect'ed shell and tries to chdir to the path given as argument, e.g.  `perl myscript.pl /tmp` or `perl myscript.pl /noexist`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Expect;

my $exp = Expect->spawn("/bin/bash")
    or die;

$exp->send ("cd ".(shift)."; echo \$?\n");
$exp->expect(2, # hardcoded timeout
    [ qr/^0/m => sub { print "chd\n" } ], # regex => sub
    [qr/^[1-9]/m => sub {print "no chd\n"}] 
);
```

P.S. I wonder how can I get (captures) (from) (my regexp) in Except. `[ qr/(\d+)/, sub { ...($1) } ]` didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi...thanks for your help but can u please explain a bit how this works for my understanding. Specifically, what is the purpose of the shift command ?

Comment: Um, sorry. I'm using it to fetch script's first parameter, so the usage is e.g. `perl script.pl /tmp`. See `perldoc -f shift` for more, it operates on `@ARGV` or `@_` by default.